# "Open with" Chrome in the Command-Line

Tags: google-chrome, command-line, cmd, command-line-arguments, command-prompt

I want to open a html-file in Chrome by using the command-line without setting Google Chrome as default-browser. How can I do this, when I don't know the path where Chrome is installed?

I'm in the folder where the file is lying:

```
 start page.html
```

Does there any "open with" Chrome function exist?

I need a solution, where I don't have to navigate to the path where chrome is lying.

Thanks!

Comment: If you use windows, you have to set the path to chrome in `environment variables`. This question maybe achieve more answers if you post in superuser instead stackoverflow

Comment: thanks for your answer. The problem is that I want to put the cmd-code to file, which others will get to run it on their computers. I can't change all their environment variables...

Comment: Well.. You have to say to windows where the executable target is located. Check [this link](http://superuser.com/questions/13783/is-there-any-command-line-tool-that-can-be-used-to-edit-environment-variables-in)

Comment: I solved it...
you can start it by 

    start chrome.exe page.html

Answer (score 1):

This command will work.

For Google Chrome:

**start chrome page.html**

For Firefox

**start firefox page.html**

But **start iexplore page.html** will not work.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the absolute path to the Chrome executable then you're reliant upon it being on the `$PATH` environment variable (or `%PATH%` on Windows).  If Chrome has been installed normally, then it's *probably* on the path anyway.

You can try running `chrome page.html` on the command line.  If the Chrome executable is on the path then this will open successfully and try to open `page.html` in a tab.

If the executable is not on the path then you will need to know the absolute path to it and run something like this instead: `/absolute/path/to/chrome page.html` or `C:\Path\To\Chrome\chrome.exe page.html` on Windows.